# Python 3.5 not cooperating with BeautifulSoup and variables

Tags: python, variables, beautifulsoup, scrape, scraper

I'm trying to write a program that can check whether or not a YouTube video is in the music category or not. I have written some code but its almost as if Python is "lying" to me. Here is the code

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXuNNqoo1WQ"
>>> html = urlopen(url).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> tags = soup.find_all(class_="content watch-info-tag-list")
>>> hasmusictag = 'href="/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ">Music</a>' in 
tags[0]
>>> print(hasmusictag)
False
>>> print(tags[0])
<ul class="content watch-info-tag-list">
<li><a class=" yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link " data-
sessionlink="ei=udFWWrG5EYqB8wSag5rgCg" href="/channel/UC-9-
kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ">Music</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, hasmusictag should return true, but it is returning false. I have no idea why. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `tags[0]` a string? Just because it can print doesn't make it so.

Comment: @Jay if "in" weren't usable with tags[0], it would give an error. I just tried this: >>> number = 12
>>> test = 1 in number
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    test = 1 in number
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: Tags is a beautifulsoup object, that's why the `in` didn't work.  If you put a `type(tag[0])` you'll see.  Nicholas' answer below should help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think @Jay is trying to tell you that the `in` operator will raise an exception, but rather that you are expecting the `in` operator to work in the same way it works for a string. In this case, `tags[0]` is an instance of the `bs4.element.Tag` class and, evidently, the `in` operator (by virtue of the `__contains__` operator overloading method) is not implemented this way.

There are a number of ways to go about making this work the way you want, but maybe the simplest would be to write the following:

```
hasmusictag = 'href="/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ">Music</a>' in str(tags[0])
```

Comment: I understand now, sorry for the misunderstanding @Jay